# How to implement a multi step navigation/filter form in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

I have just started working with ReactJS. I have 3 lists consisting of `li` elements.

The second list is populated with options depending on what option the user selects from the first list. Likewise the third list is populated with options depending on what was selected in the second list, so it is a three step process.

So far I have two components, '[FilterForm](https://pastebin.com/U3gW1LEz)' and '[StepTwo](https://pastebin.com/aNrwa1GM)'.

I have got the second list populating depending on what the user selects from the first list.

I'm looking for guidance/suggestions how I can go about implementing the populating of the third list?

Appreciate any help.

Comment: you can try redux. it's may achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend keeping in state of FilterForm both selections, for drop down 1 as well as 2.

`this.state = { selectedOptionLevel1: '' , selectedOptionLevel2: ''};`

And handle second drop down click to update selectedOptionLevel2 in state which will cause third drop down to rerender

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So should I keep everything in one component?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Assuming I split out the population of list 2 and 3 into two components; stepTwo and stepThree - how can I notify FilterForm that a option has been selected?

Comment: To do that add a prop on stepTwo called, optionSelectedCallback. It will be passed <stepTwo optionSelectedCallback={this.handleSelectionChanged}/> with handleSelectionChanged defined in FilterForm. Inside the component  stepTwo, the event handler of dropdown should call this method as this.props.optionSelectedCallback. Hope that makes sense

Comment: Apologies - I'm struggling to follow. I had three components in mind;

1) FilterForm, 2) StepTwo and 3) StepThree

Comment: sorry about that @Sid. 
To elaborate, handleSelectionChanged in filterForm should update state's value of selected options in level 1 and 2. 
stepThree will be similar to stepThree but it doesn't need the callback prop because we are not doing anything when selection changes in dropdown3.

Comment: No need to apologise. I eventually understood what you meant. Thanks for your help. I'm passing down the onclick handler function to step2 but when trying to change the state in the handler function (in filterform component) it doesn't set the state...

Comment: Ignore my previous comment I had to bind the click handler function to the component instance - did it in the constructor.